# Is it possible to import OSM data based on coordinates into QGIS3?

Tags: openstreetmap, download

I'm trying to import Openstreetmap building polygons to QGIS 3.4 based on coordinates: I have coordinates of sampling spots and would like to import all buildings within the vicinity of say 1 km of these spots.

I have tried to just import all building polygons for an entire region (in Germany) with the idea to make a buffer around sampling spots and save only buildings that are subsequently in the vicinity but my (half-year old) computer is to slow to compute that.

I have also tried to use the QuickOSM plugin but it apparently only accepts the name of cities or villages to load data and not coordinates.

How do I (batch) download building polygons from OSM around certain coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way for big areas like Germany:

1. Run PostGIS database
2. Download OSM dump in pbf format for country, see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm
3. Import pbf to PostGIS using osm2pgsql
4. Add planet_osm_polygons layer to QGIS, using filter `"building" IS NOT NULL AND "building" <> 'no'`
5. Use this layer in QGIS same way as file.

This workflow can run in Ubuntu, Mac OS and Windows